# itertools.groupby: iterate over groups pairwise

Tags: python, python-itertools

How can I iterate over `groupby` results in pairs? What I tried isn't quite working:

```
from itertools import groupby,izip

groups = groupby([(1,2,3),(1,2),(1,2),(3,4,5),(3,4)],key=len)

def grouped(iterable, n):    
    return izip(*[iterable]*n)

for g, gg in grouped(groups,2):
    print list(g[1]), list(gg[1])
```

Output I get:

```
[] [(1, 2), (1, 2)]
[] [(3, 4)]
```

Output I would like to have:

```
[(1, 2, 3)] [(1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(3, 4, 5)] [(3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools as IT

groups = IT.groupby([(1,2,3),(1,2),(1,2),(3,4,5),(3,4)], key=len)
groups = (list(group) for key, group in groups)

def grouped(iterable, n):
    return IT.izip(*[iterable]*n)

for p1, p2  in grouped(groups, 2):
    print p1, p2
```

yields

```
[(1, 2, 3)] [(1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(3, 4, 5)] [(3, 4)]
```

---

The code you posted is very interesting. It has a mundane problem, and a subtle problem.

The mundane problem is that itertools.groupby returns an iterator which outputs both a key and a group on each iteration.
Since you are interested in only the groups, not the keys, you need something like

```
groups = (group for key, group in groups)
```

The subtle problem is more difficult to explain -- I'm not really sure I understand it fully. Here is my guess: The iterator returned by `groupby` has turned its input,

```
[(1,2,3),(1,2),(1,2),(3,4,5),(3,4)]
```

into an iterator. That the groupby iterator is wrapped around the underlying data iterator is analogous to how a `csv.reader` is wrapped around an underlying file object iterator. You get one pass through this iterator and one pass only. The itertools.izip function, in the process of pairing items in `groups`, causes the `groups` iterator to advance from the first item to the second. Since you only get one pass through the iterator, the first item has been consumed, so when you call `list(g[1])` it is empty.

A <strike>not-so-satisfying</strike> fix to this problem is to convert the iterators in `groups` into lists:

```
groups = (list(group) for key, group in groups)
```

so `itertools.izip` will not prematurely consume them. Edit: On second thought, this fix is not so bad. `groups` remains an iterator, and only turns the `group` into a list as it is consumed.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to look at the second key from the `groupby`, you are forcing it to iterate that far into the source iterator. Since there is normally nowhere to store the items from the first group, they are simply discarded.

So now we understand why we'll need to make sure we've stored the items from the first group before we try to look at the key (or the items) of the second group.

Some people are sure to hate this, but

```
>>> groups = groupby([(1, 2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4)], key=len)
>>> for i, j in ((list(i[1]), list(next(groups)[1])) for i in groups):
...     print i, j
... 
[(1, 2, 3)] [(1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(3, 4, 5)] [(3, 4)]
```